# How to allow the execution of inline event handler in CSP with the 'unsafe-hashes'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss, content-security-policy

We are trying to enable Content Security Policy to prevent XSS, so we put the script-src 'self' in order to avoid inline scripts.  However our application is using a third party javascript library that has inline event handler.

We read that adding the unsafe-hashes attribute with a sha256 hash in order to allow this specific library to execute inline events:

We added the following policy in the web.cofig:

However is giving us the following error in Google Chrome browser console:

maskedinput.js:7 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-attr 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-TS+Ok6crNR4qdKYT6T5jwMHjsPdCzbg7dmT0eWCSN20='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Any idea how to avoid inline script, but at the same time allowing this specific library to run inline events.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unsafe-hashes` like so.
Let's say you have:

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World')">Show Alert</button>
```

then you can use this command to generate your hash:

```
echo -n "alert('Hello World')" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64
```

and then you should use it like:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-YOUR_HASH_HERE';
```

in this case the hash `YOUR_HASH_HERE` would be: `ztv5rbjekwogmr7erW0rKA6H3gY4jEFwwdz2cl8bk1I=`